# Gulp watch stucks at the end and says starting task

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

So I have a really simple build file that stuck for no reason( Or I think it is for no reason )

What's been happening is, when I try `gulp watch` it stucks forever. Like even if I change files(file1, file2, or any files that is being watched) it does not trigger anything.

```
✗ gulp --version
[09:13:09] CLI version 2.0.1
[09:13:09] Local version 4.0.0



const gulp = require('gulp');
const {watch, series} = gulp;

const webpack = require('webpack-stream');

gulp.task('task1', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/file1.js')
        .pipe(webpack({
            output: {
                filename: 'file1.map.js',
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});


gulp.task('task2', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/file2.js')
        .pipe(webpack({
            output: {
                filename: 'file2.map.js',
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('copy-artifacts', function() {
    gulp.src('dist/file1.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../build/scripts'))

});

gulp.task('watch', function (cb) {

    watch(['utility/*.js', 'src/*.js'], {}, series('task1', 'task2', 'copy-artifacts'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the return and then it will be able to complete

```
gulp.task('copy-artifacts', function() {
return gulp.src('dist/file1.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../build/scripts'));

});
```

Comment: YOU NAILED IT, this was one of those dumb mistakes that even eyes doesn't catch it. Also, that's what happen when you copy from your previous codes. I wrote a long gulp file aggggges ago and copied stuff over....

Thank you